# ++ operator on a pointer to struct member

Tags: c

I came across a piece of code that reads:

```
++myStruct->counter
```

I'm confused on how the ++ operator and -> operator are evaluated here. The ++ has precedence over the -> operator and left to right evaluation. It appears the ++ operator would actually perform pointer arithmetic on 'myStruct', not increment the counter member.

Comment: http://cs.indstate.edu/CS202/CPT.pdf   `->` has higher precedence than `++`

Comment: "The ++ has precedence over the -> operator". Where did you get this piece of informaton?

Comment: IMO that's **bad** code.  Not every programmer is going to have the precedence of operators memorized, and even the ones that think they do don't have perfect recall.  That code should be something like `(++myStruct)->counter` or `++(myStruct->counter)` to make the intent clear.

Comment: Apparently I confused the prefix and postfix precedence. I agree this code is dangerous.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I could not agree more.  From time to time (though thankfully rarely) you get these terse-first pundits show up insisting that you should not use more parentheses than needed.  This is and always has been a horrendously bad idea.  Use whatever means at your disposal to help the exhausted engineer hopped up on caffeine at 3am to read your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is no more dangerous than `++foo.bar`. That is, not at all.

Comment: @n.m. In my experience, the worst coders are those that think they're too good to make mistakes, and use that misplaced self-assurance to write code that's more complex than it needs to be, for example writing code that depends on another coder's complete understanding of operator precedence to correctly interpret the too-complex code.  Writing clear, maintainable production code is **not** a coding contest for boosting your ego.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you are not sure about relative precedence of `.` and `->`, you have no business touching C code of any complexity. It's basic knowledge. Nothing complex about it at all.

Comment: @n.m. Glad to see you're assuming no one else ever needs to look at or modify your code.  Another thing I've learned is the best programmers are those that know how **bad** they are at it so they **never** rely on fallible things like human recall when writing code.

Comment: @tgm1024 - We seem to have found one of your "terse-first pundits".  :-D

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Would you insist that idiomatic expressions like `*p++` always be written as `*(p++)`?

Comment: @JohnBode I'd first ask why you felt like you had to characterize that expression as "idiomatic", as if to lend it more legitimacy.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I consider understanding of how `->` works a basic prerequisite of being a competent C programmer. If you think I shouldn't, well, I won't hire you.

Comment: @n.m. And you still haven't said what you gain by leaving out the parenthesis.  Also, nice job moving the goalposts from your defending what I think is an overly complex statement with multiple operators in four characters of code to trying to claim I don't understand what a `->` operator does.  I hope your code is more focused.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Because it shows up all over the place; it's enshrined in many [`strcpy`](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strcpy) implementations as `while ( (*dst++ = *src++) );`, it's featured in the Wikipedia entry on [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device); it's as commonly used an expression as just about anything else.  You almost *never* see it written as `*(p++)`.  Hence, *idiomatic*.

Comment: @zacharoni16: as a standalone expression, this code isn't dangerous *at all*.  It does the right thing (updates the value of the `counter` member).  As part of a larger expression it *might* be dangerous, but that's because of the side effect, not precedence.

Comment: @JohnBode Well said, but that only describes what makes your example idiomatic, not why you labelled it as such.  FWIW, though, that code is cognitively much simpler than the preincrement of a field accessed through a pointer.  The very fact that asking what that code does created this very discussion is evidence itself that `++ptr->field` is bad code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I *labeled* it as idiomatic because it *is* idiomatic.  So are expressions like `++ptr->field` and `ptr->field++`.  Both do what most people *expect* them to do, which is to update `ptr->field`.  The only time you should explicitly group is when you're doing something most people *don't* expect, like `(ptr++)->field` or `(++ptr)->field` (analogous to the difference between `a + b * c` and `(a + b) * c`).  Adding parens where they aren't needed just adds visual clutter and makes the expression harder to read.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Isn't it clear? I gain less noise per line of code. Less noise means less attention to noise and more attention to things that do matter. I don't quite understand what exactly I have moved and where. Are we still discussing `++myStruct->counter`? Do *you* find it hard to understand because *you* don't quite remember the precedence of `->`? I would consider it just about equivalent of not knowing the relative precedence of binary `+` and `*`, not because a competent programmer blindly memorizes them, but because they understand *why* there is no other option.

Comment: @n.m. Are you really claiming parenthesis are **noise**?

Comment: @JohnBode  The code *is* a lot of things. Out of everything it may be, you **selected** "idiomatic" to characterize your example. Your defense of not using parenthesis is that parenthesis makes code "harder to read"?  When they merely express the coder's actual intent?  And are all over C code anyway?

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are shifting the question. Redundant parentheses may or may not be be noise (sometimes they are), but this is not the question. The question is whether a competent C programmer finds the precedence of `->` hard to understand. Anyway I don't think this discussion is productive.

Comment: @n.m. Questioning the "logic" behind **your** argument that "[you] gain less noise per line of code" is not "shifting the question".  You claimed that the parenthesis in `++(ptr->field)` are **noise**.  You posted that, and now you can't defend it.  Not only that, you had the temerity to question my competence, but now you claim those parenthesis are noise?!?!  Wow.  I claim those parenthesis make the intent absolutely clear, and furthermore that the very existence of this question is proof that making the intent of the code clear is necessary for the vast majority of programmers.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I will repeat my claims for convenience of attacking them. (1) Yes, this particular pair of parentheses is noise (2) Yes, anyone who needs parentheses here doesn't quite understand C. Likewise for the constructs whose idiomatic qualities you questioned in other comments I don't believe that the existence of this question shows anything, except people at various stages of learning programming languages being able to ask questions here. I think I really truly don't have anything to add to this discussion.

Comment: @n.m. Me:  Parentheses make intent clear where simply relying on operator precedence does not, parentheses also make sure a later programmer of unknown experience and competence will understand the code.  The use of parenthesis makes sure the code is clear, the intent is clear, and interpretation does not rely on fallible human memory.  You:  They're unnecessary noise.  Again: dangerous programmers are those that think they can't make a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ++ has precedence over the -> operator and left to right evaluation.

This is not correct - postfix operators like `->` have higher precedence than unary (prefix) operators `++` and `--`.  The expression is parsed as

```
++(myStruct->counter)
```

so the `counter` member of `myStruct` is being incremented.

Answer (score 3):

The *postfix* increment and decrement have the same precedence as the `->` operator and left-to-right associativity, but the *prefix* increment and decrement are after. So the code does increment the variable `counter` and not the `myStruct`.

Comment: We answered at the exact same second. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the *prefix* `++`/`--` operator has lower precedence thatn the `->` operator. The *suffix* one has the same precedence, but left-to-right associativity.